# What is the sequence of actions when using promises in useEffect hook in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

In the code below I was expecting that inside the useEffect hook console.log procedure will log the list of the tickets fetched by getAllTickets function because list of the tickets is returned without error.However console.log results in logging an empty array that I set up in the state initially. It seems that console.log is somehow preceding the fetch process and following setTickets hook. Could someone help to clarify this confusion?

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as React from 'react';

import { getAllTickets } from './api';

const App = () => {
  const [tickets, setTickets] = React.useState([]);
  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getAllTickets()
      .then((res) => setTickets([...res]))
      .then(() => console.log(tickets))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }, []);

  const renderTickets = tickets.map((t) => (
    <div key={t.id}>
      <p>{t.description}</p>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      {renderTickets}
      <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Add ticket</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

getAllTickets fetches list of tickets from db as below

```
export const getAllTickets = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/tickets');
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not that there's a sequencing issue. It's that the function logging the `tickets` value is logging an old value.

Your `useEffect` callback is created each time your component function is called, but because your dependency array is empty, only the *first* of those functions is ever called by `useEffect`. That first function closes over the `tickets` constant for the call to your component function that created the callback (the first call), in which `tickets` is an empty array. So although `setTickets` updates your state item, which will cause your component function to be called again, your `useEffect` callback (or more accurately, the callbacks it creates) continue to use the old value.

If you want to see the updated array, you can use `res`:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  getAllTickets()
    .then((res) => {
          const ticketsReceived = [...res]; // Why the shallow copy?
          setTickets(ticketsReceived);
          console.log(ticketsReceived);
     })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you TJ for this great explanation. with respect to shallow copy, I honestly don't have any meaningful reason to use shallow copy vs not shallow copy, I just thought that this is the pattern in setting state.

Comment: Every time I come across closure I do extensive research and think that I finally understood everything until next time I come across closure again just to find out that I hadn't understood it properly

Comment: @esentai = LOL - We've all been there. :-)

Comment: @esentai I created this sandbox just for a closer insight, check the console https://codesandbox.io/s/r74cp